# Text in a textbox to be able to use a button

Tags: c#, vba

i need some help with this now.

I want to make a button that is only pressable if you have text in a specific textbox.

I am just a beginner and I do programming for fun. I use visual basic c#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you progrma in Visual Basic C#? Please try to write some code and post a specific problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `TextChanged` event of the textbox, you can check the `Length` of the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. If it's `0`, disable the button. Otherwise, enable it (also, set the `Button` to `Disabled` in the form's `Load` event, so it can't be pressed until text is entered into the box:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text.Length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the event TextChanged and in the method that's linked to the event, check to see if there's any text in the textbox. If there is, enable the button, if there isn't disable the button.

Consider the following:

```
static void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1UpdateButtonState;
}

static void textBox1UpdateButtonState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Notes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

FYI, you can also subscribe to the event in the Visual Studio interface directly if you double click the event name in the properties window and write your code that way.